# Center a text at the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

I've got a `div` for my header and a text in that div. Now I have figured out how to put that text at the bottom of the `div` but I can't seem to put it in the center.

`text-align: center;` didn't work.

```
#heading {
 position: relative;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#acbfb9,#cae1da); /* For Safari */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#acbfb9,#cae1da); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#acbfb9,#cae1da); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
 background: linear-gradient(#acbfb9,#cae1da);
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
}

#title {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20px;  
}


<div id="heading">
    <h1 id="title">StrAgility</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: add `left:0;right:0`....

Comment: Be better put html in next

Comment: HTML is in beginpost. Just 2 simple div's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `#title` has not width set so it has the width of the text it contains if you use `text-align:center;` it won't center in the `#header`.

So you need to set `width:100%` on `#title` to and then `text-align:center;` will work as you expect.

see this
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7tXUs/1/)**

CSS :

```
 #title {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 20px;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Text-align center doesn't work for you as you'd expect as you haven't set the width of the title div. As such, it's currently sitting in the centre of the div, it's just that the div isn't wider than your text. So to change that add 'width:100%' and then add 'text-align:center'.

Ah, beaten to it.